# How much (if any) tax should I add to an invoice issued by my Delaware LLC while being in California to a Company in Ukraine?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company

I live in California (San Mateo County). I recently started an LLC (in Delaware) since I am running a SaaS business on the side. I didn't start it in California since I am planning to move to a different state very soon.

Now I need to issue an invoice to a customer in Ukraine. Assuming the invoice is for $250 how much tax do I need to add to receive $250 in my bank account? And which tax?

Comment: Does either state require you to pay sales tax for the service you are providing?

Comment: Seems like CA does not: https://blog.taxjar.com/saas-california-sales-tax/ and for Delware I found this: https://revenue.delaware.gov/frequently-asked-questions/internet-sales-faqs/ seems like they have a Gross Receipts Tax. Whatever that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to collect any US sales tax because that is based on the location of the buyer and the buyer is outside of the US.

Ukraine likely has VAT.  Most small businesses in the US do not collect VAT because (1) it seems likely that other countries' laws do not apply to a business that operates entirely within the US, (2) it is a huge pain to track for every country in the world, and (3) as a small US business it is very unlikely that a foreign country would enforce tax collection.

TL,DR: Just invoice for $250.